# Importing Google libraries with Maven in Eclipse?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm following this example, http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2Draft10 and I paste in the code however the following lines give errors (cannot be resolved):

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessTokenRequest.GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl;
```

The same page says ok bro no problem just add this to Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately I don't know jack about Maven. I don't have a POM.XML (I created another project and still no pom.xml).

Comment: I don't know much about Maven either, but in one project, I use the Maven plug in for Eclipse and right click the project, Maven, Resolve Dependencies.